# How can Environment Reflections influence the color of the cube?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Let's say I create a new scene and paste a simple gray cube in there with color #4D4D4D, for example.

- If I go to **Lightning->Scene->Environment** and set the **Intensity Multiplier** in the **Environment Lightning** section to **0** I will have my cube darkened.
- Then if I set the **Intensity Multiplier** in the **Environment Reflections** section to **0** I will have my cube darkened **again**.

**Environment Lightning** configures ambient lightning so I understand why my cube became darker, but why the same thing happened with **Environment Reflections**? My cube does not have a reflection probe and it is the only object in the scene?

**How can Environment Reflections influence the color of the cube?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming-related. Try gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a property of StandardShader. By deafult it takes the skybox reflection into lighting calculation (using spherical harmonics simplification I believe). This happens automatically in Unity even if there are no Reflection Probes in the scene (Which override the default, skybox probe).

If that effect is undesired, you can find StandardShader source code (its digged on Unity3D website), make a copy, and comment out lines that the calculated skybox light intensity.

Comment: I set Metallic and Smoothness to 0 and turned reflections off for my material and Environment Reflections still influences my object. So if I need to change this behaviour I have to dig into the source code of the shader?

Comment: you need to change the shader. Even if there are no reflections per se, lighting is still being transported from the skybox